# Parent controller not resolving parameter "User $user", but "$id"

Tags: php, routes, symfony4, fosrestbundle

I have a parent controller "UserController", and a child controller "UserCartController". Unlike all other controllers, FOSRest refuses the following definition:

```php
class UserController extends AbstractFOSRestController
{
    // [...]

    /**
     * @param User $user
     * @return View
     */
    public function getUserAction(User $user): View
    {
        return new View([]);
    }
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
Every parent controller must have `get{SINGULAR}Action(\$id)` method where {SINGULAR} is a singular form of associated object in [...]/config/../src/GDS/[BundleNameHere]/Resources/config/user_routes.yaml (which is being imported from "[...]/config/routes.yaml"). Make sure there is a loader supporting the "rest" type.
```

Once I change the head of the way as follows...

```php
class UserController extends AbstractFOSRestController
{
    // [...]

    /**
     * @param User $user
     * @return View
     */
    public function getUserAction($id): View
    {
        return new View([]);
    }
}
```

The error no longer appears. What is the reason? In all other controllers, you can resolve model instances.

As a result, my routes don't look very elegant. :)

```
/api/users/{id}.{_format}

# vs.

/api/carts/{cart}.{_format}
```

Thanks in advance!